# Robotino ROS pcl::VoxelGrid<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void>

Tags: ros, pcl, robotino, pcl-1.7

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

i checked out the robotino packages from  http://svn.openrobotino.org/robotino-ros-pkg/trunk/ and want to build them via rosmake. When i type *rosmake robotino* i get the following error and i have no idea what to do about it:

```
In file included from /home/daniel/Desktop/robotino/trunk/robotino/robotino_node/src/KinectROS.cpp:10:0:
/usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/filters/voxel_grid.h: In instantiation of 'class pcl::VoxelGrid<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> > >': /home/daniel/Desktop/robotino/trunk/robotino/robotino_node/src/KinectROS.cpp:124:44: required from here /usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/filters/voxel_grid.h:474:61: error: no type namen 'type' in struct pcl::traits::fieldList<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> > >
typedef typename pcl::traits::fieldList<PointT>::type FieldList;
```

I really have no idea what i have to do here, i thaught it would be no problem to build these packages.There are a few more erros like this but this is the first one. Maybe i can resolve the others by myself when i get this one fixed. Can anyone help me here?

Best regards,
Daniel

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190419/robotino-ros-pcl::voxelgrid%3Csensor_msgs::pointcloud2_%3Cstd::allocator%3Cvoid%3E/) by [Missing](https://answers.ros.org/users/19975/missing/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2014-08-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-08-17**:
Which version of ROS was this developed for? Which version of ROS are you trying to use it with? I think some of the PCL point types and ROS integration changed between ROS Groovy and Hydro.

**Comment by [Missing](https://answers.ros.org/users/19975/missing/) on 2014-08-18**:
I try to use it with ROS Indigo. I know that PCL is a stand-alone project since quite a time and because of that i use pcl-1.7 instead. I tried to install an older ROS version but it doesn't work. It tells me that ros-groovy-desktop-full has unmet dependencies?! Is it possible to fix this within Indigo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suspect the robotino stack was developed against an older version of ROS, and uses an older version of the PCL types.

The robotinio repository you linked to has a `migrate_to_catkin` branch which may work on newer versions of ROS: http://svn.openrobotino.org/robotino-ros-pkg/branches/robotino/migrate_to_catkin/

If that doesn't work, you'll probably have to follow the [PCL section of the Hydro Migration guide](http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Migration#PCL) to upgrade the code you're having trouble with to the new PCL types.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-08-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Missing](https://answers.ros.org/users/19975/missing/) on 2014-08-19**:
Thanks for your answer, i will try the migrate_to_catkin branch. For the moment it works to comment out the parts which use the ROSKinect.cpp class.